# angular and jquery: binding does not refresh

Tags: angularjs

I have a jquery colorPicker component.
in myApp.js, I use that snippet:

```
    myApp.controller('chatController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.texts = [];      
    $scope.color = "#00FF00";
    $scope.test = "before";

$('button#color').simpleColorPicker({ onChangeColor: function(color) {
        console.log(color);
        $scope.color = "#FF0000";
        $scope.test = "after";
     } });
```

I have a {{color}} and {{test}} in my view.

Problem is: when colorPicker triggers changed, this is not reflected !
Instead I need to refresh some other data bindings and then {{test}} and {{color}} change.

What is wrong ?

Comment: You need a `$scope.apply(function(){$scope.color = "#FF0000";
        $scope.test = "after";})` inside onchange color

Comment: It is angular basics.. You need to manually force digest cycle when out of angular...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.test = "after";
$scope.$apply(); // tells Angular to update all the bindings
```